# Postfix - Sendmail impossible to Yahoo mailboxes

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using the lastest version LTS of ubuntu and i just set up a mail server using postfix.
However, I noticed that the emails sent to Yahoo just disappear somehow in the web. Everything is fine in the log and the queue is empty.
For GMail and Hotmail mailboxes in the contrary, the emails are actually sent and can be read properly.

Does anyone have an idea about it?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need SPF DNS record, reverse DNS, and probably whitelist your IP at yahoo, basically check spam folder on yahoo and whitelist these emails, check the log files on your SMTP server what is the error code when sending mail to yahoo server, check your IP on e.g. http://robtex.com/ if you are clear from blacklists.

Comment: Good list. I haven't ticked all of those off yet. However, I do get emails from 12.04 LTS/Postfix delivered to Yahoo OK without whitelisting and an SPF record. I do have a reverse DNS PTR record though, so you might want to prioritise that one. I'd also add to the list an A Record for your MX record domain and ensuring that Postfix's myhostname entry matches what's in your MX record.

Comment: IP numbers are different, if it's ex-dsl or something range, or the port 25 is filtered like in EC2.

Comment: Yahoo use DKIM rather than SPF don't they?

Comment: Yeah, and Hotmail senderid, but it's good to have it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at blacklists yet?

[This](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) is a good one to check, that checks most RBLs.

I believe Yahoo! uses external RBLs and their own proprietary filtering system, but I couldn't find any Yahoo! specific blacklists.

Also, check and make sure you're using reverse DNS (PTR records) for you domains.

If you're sending bulk mail from that server, I'd also read their [Best Practices information](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&page=content&id=SLN3435).